# Meteor API vs external API

Tags: meteor, architecture

Basically I want a real time application (Meteor) so I can see a real time dashboard

This back-end (Meteor server) would eventually be hit by some external application via API to get data from the DB (example: mobile App) or add some entries (not from the front-end)

My question is : What is better: create a Meteor API **OR** create an external server (ExpressJS) that would be connected to Meteor DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor is great for building Full Stack apps (front end + back end), and has native support for MongoDB, which together are powerful for building real-time apps (using DDP for example) relatively easily.

Express is an MVC Framework built in Javascript and powered by Node. You will usually have to consider more technologies and frameworks when using Express (MEAN stack), which has a steeper learning curve when compared with Meteor.

Given that you're intending to develop a Full Stack app, building an API using Meteor is more straightforward. As suggested by Mikkel, [restivus](https://atmospherejs.com/nimble/restivus) would be the Meteor package to consider for building your REST service.

If complexity is not a hurdle, using Express is likely to yield to a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate express with Meteor - probably a better solution, because you only need one server.

There are Meteor packages for creating REST API's that work well https://atmospherejs.com/nimble

Another approach (my preference) would be to use GraphQL server with Meteor. Apollo Client and Server were developed by the Meteor Development Group (MDG) https://github.com/abhiaiyer91/sample-graphql-meteor-server